# How rearrange values inside array and make each of them always start with numeric/integer in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string, laravel, filter

I have an array of strings `$data`. For Example:

```
$data = array(
    "foo",
    "56",
    "hello",
    "world",
    "!",
    "9",
    "hei",
    "10",
    "good",
    "morning"
);
```

According to the example above, `$data` is consist of string, numeric and it could be contain a special character. In this case, I would like to rearrange the values inside `$data` to be `$newData` like example below:

```
$newData = [
    "56 hello world !", 
    "9 hei",
    "10 good morning"
];
```

So, each value inside `$newData`, should be start with numeric/integer value. Then, it should be followed by another value inside `$data` which is a string (not numeric value), and it should be used `space` as separator.

To solve this task, I am trying to create a function `checkNumeric($d)` that try to determinate each value inside `$data` is numeric or not numeric.

This is part of my code:

```
foreach($data as $d){
    if (checkNumeric($d) == true){
        $newData [] .= $d;
    }
}
```

In that code I am trying to create a loop to get each value inside `$data` and check if each of them is numeric or not. If it is numeric I will assign it into another variable that I called `$newData`.

However, It does not show the proper result that I expect. Is there any idea how I can modify the code? So that, it can show each value inside `$data` which is start with numeric value?

Comment: You would start by clearly stating the criteria by which you group the strings. For instance: "Start a new string whenever a number is encountered.". Then you know you've got to loop over the array, and create a new array while using this criteria.

Comment: That input is again defined badly. That array would generate an error

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just try to edit my question, I hope now it show the proper information with proper input :)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I see I just try to take a look and modify the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is simple: iterate over the strings and:

- if the string is numeric then insert it into result array
- otherwise append the string to the last string in result array

```php
$array = array(
    "foo",
    "56",
    "hello",
    "world",
    "!",
    "9",
    "hei",
    "10",
    "good",
    "morning"
);
$result = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
    if (count($result) === 0 || ctype_digit($value)) {
        $result[] = $value;
    } else {
        $result[count($result) - 1] .= " " . $value;
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Produces the following result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "56 hello world !"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "9 hei"
  [3]=>
  string(15) "10 good morning"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I have tried it, however, I got `Undefined offset: 1`. Any advice of this?

Comment: Works for sample data. Do you have arrays where first element is non-numeric?

Comment: Yes, I have. But, in my opinion, I can Ignore the first element which is non-numeric, by using `array_slice`. And I can use the the solution above straight away.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?php

$string = '
"56"
"hello"
"world"
"!"
"9"
"hei"
"10"
"good"
"morning"
';

$array_string = explode("\n", $string);
$group = array();
$i = 0;

foreach($array_string as $line) {
    $line = trim(str_replace('"', "", $line));
    if(is_numeric($line) === true && strlen($line) > 0) {
        $i++;
        $group[$i] = $line;
    } elseif(strlen($line) > 0) {
        $group[$i] .= " ".$line;
    }
}

var_dump($group);
```

Comment: I think It will be better we do not change the `$data` as an array from my example, to be `$string` as string on  your suggest solution. I think solution from `Claret Nnamocha` could be good solution on this case. However, Thank you for your answer. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can match them with, [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/10a619d2174894af47e4b3a2d75a253a347ff13f)

```
preg_match_all('/([\d]+[\D]+)/',join(" ", $array),$matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the preg_match in built function in php.
Update your code to look like this

```php
<?php
   $words = [     
     "56",
     "hello",
     "world",
     "!",
     "9",
     "hei",
     "10",
     "good",
     "morning"
   ];
   $string = implode(' ',$words);
   $pattern = '#(\d+(\s|[a-zA-Z]+|!)+)#';
   preg_match_all ($pattern , $string, $matches); 
   print_r($matches[0]); // Outputs Array ( [0] => 56 hello world ! [1] => 9 hei [2] => 10 good morning )
```